# Files aren't getting uploaded

Tags: php

I'm on linux, running xampp. index.php

```
    <form class="well" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="file">Select a file to upload</label>
            <input type="file" name="file">
            <p class="help-block">Only jpg, jpeg, png, wav, mp3, wav and mp4 files are allowed.</p>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value="Upload">
    </form>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        $name     = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $tmpName  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $error    = $_FILES['file']['error'];
        $size     = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $ext      = strtolower(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        switch ($error) {
            case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
                $valid = true;
                //validate file extensions
                if ( !in_array($ext, array('jpg','jpeg','png','mp3', 'mp4', 'wav', 'webm')) ) {
                    $valid = false;
                    $response = 'Invalid file extension.';
                }
                //validate file size
                /*if ( $size/1024/1024 > 2 ) {
                    $valid = false;
                    $response = 'File size is exceeding maximum allowed size.';
                }*/
                //upload file
                if ($valid) {
                    $targetPath =  'uploads/';

                    move_uploaded_file($tmpName,$targetPath);
                    header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;
                    exit;
                }
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                $response = 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                $response = 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
                $response = 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                $response = 'No file was uploaded.';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
                $response = 'Missing a temporary folder. Introduced in PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.3.';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
                $response = 'Failed to write file to disk. Introduced in PHP 5.1.0.';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
                $response = 'File upload stopped by extension. Introduced in PHP 5.2.0.';
                break;
            default:
                $response = 'Unknown error';
            break;
        }

        echo $response;
    }

    ?>
```

Phpinfo: file upload on, Max file size 128M. `uploads` folder is empty, it's in the root directory where the script is located, no errors are displayed and nothing seems wrong with the script

Comment: I asked on the chat, no answers. i tried to format the code using freeformatter.com/if it's readable then I'll always use it, I'd love your feadback

Comment: are you working on a sub folder? In wamp, when I create a project folder inside www folder, my upload features messed up. Maybe you should check root www folder. Create your upload folder in there?

Comment: @Ali yes im working in a sub folder, is it a xampp problem? if yes then no need to fix it coz in production i wont be on xampp

Comment: You said you've created uploads folder in root where script is located. Can you create an upload folder where "script folder is located"? Example for Windows: C:\Wamp\www\myproject is your project folder. C:\Wamp\www\myproject\up is your uploaded folder. I suggest you to create C:\Wamp\www\up and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the return value of `move_uploaded_file`.

```
if ($valid) 
{
    $targetPath =  'uploads/';

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpName,$targetPath))
    {
       header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;
       exit;
    }
    else
    {
        $response = 'Moving the file to the target directory failed.';
    }
}
```

If this gives you an error, use an absolute path for `$targetPath`.

Edit: You also need to include the file name to use as the target, not only the directory. So change the code to:

```
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $targetPath . $name))
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

So you kinda need to get to the folder you are trying to access. I had the same problem i think a while back. The solution i found was doing this with the $targetpath:

You need to get the webserver path, in order to do this you use the `dirname(__FILE__)` function. Depending on how far you are going to go in the file path. Forexample i needed to access a folder "nydemo1/bilder/images/folders/" then i needed this for my filepath variable:

`dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))` //because this is 3 folders deep

Hope this helps